# SQLite3: Recovering database from "Invalid file format"

Tags: sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

After a power surge got my SQLite3 database corrupted "the hard way". Trying to open it in *DB Broweser for SQLite* gives:

> Invalid file format.

[image]

**How to recover?**

Answer (score 0):

The situation is curable using *sqlite3* binaries and following steps from here:

http://www.froebe.net/blog/2015/05/27/error-sqlite-database-is-malformed-solved/

**Q:** I am getting an empty *.db* file after following the steps.

**A:** In this case *less* through the dump (sql file) to see if it ends with the following command:

```
ROLLBACK; -- due to errors
```

If so, you have to replace this line with *COMMIT* command. To do so run:

```
sed -i '$d' <your_dump_file.sql>

echo "COMMIT;" >> <your_dump_file.sql>
```

This will do the job.